# Thingsboard Multiple telemetry records

Tags: thingsboard, telemetry

I have a data convertor which takes a single set of readings from one of my devices and produces a "telemetry" object. This then gets stored in the database, and I can see it ok in the dashboard. An example:

```
{
"deviceName": "0000000000005003",
"deviceApp": "EnviroSense",
"deviceType": "EnviroSense",
"telemetry": {
    "Temperature": 26.29,
    "Humidity": 59.96,
    "AirPressure": 1019.5,
    "GasResistance": 45,
    "CO2": 902
    "ts": 1631044931
}
```

}

However, I now need to send multiple readings from my sensor in a single block, then split them out at the thingsboard end into multiple timestamped records. e.g. read sensors every 10 seconds, send six at a time every minute. I tried altering my data decoder to give an array of telemetry objects, but I only ever see the last one in the array in the dashboard. What is the proper way to construct an array like this? My attempt so far is:

```
[{
"deviceName": "0000000000005003",
"deviceApp": "EnviroSense",
"deviceType": "EnviroSense",
"telemetry": {
    "Temperature": 26.29,
    "Humidity": 59.96,
    "AirPressure": 1019.5,
    "GasResistance": 45,
    "CO2": 902
},
"ts": 1631044931
```

}, {
"deviceName": "0000000000005003",
"deviceApp": "EnviroSense",
"deviceType": "EnviroSense",
"telemetry": {
"Temperature": 28.29,
"Humidity": 59.96,
"AirPressure": 1019.5,
"GasResistance": 45,
"CO2": 902
},
"ts": 1631044933
}]

Answer (score 2):

You're on the right track, just ever so slightly the wrong format.
Using your example, I'll edit it to the correct format.

```
[
  {
  "deviceName": "0000000000005003",
  "deviceApp": "EnviroSense",
  "deviceType": "EnviroSense",
  "telemetry": {
        "ts": timestamp-in-milliseconds,
        "values": {
            "Temperature": 26.29,
            "Humidity": 59.96,
            "AirPressure": 1019.5,
            "GasResistance": 45,
            "CO2": 902
        }
  },
  {
   // next block
  }
]
```

Just make sure your timestamp is in milliseconds or you will get some funky results.

I've done this in my solution, will attach two messages (out of the 50ish in the payload) below as further example

```
[{
    "deviceName": "864292042802023",
    "deviceType": "tracker",
    "attributes": {
        "last_seen": 1633040864382,
        "sensorModel": "FMC130",
        "application": "Vehicle Tracker",
        "integrationName": "Teltonika FMC130",
        "Total Odometer": 24153145,
        "GSM Signal": 5,
        "External Voltage": 14677,
        "Battery Voltage": 3915,
        "Battery Current": 0,
        "GNSS Status": 1,
        "Ignition": 0,
        "Movement": 1,
        "Active GSM Operator": 50501
    },
    "telemetry": {
        "ts": 1633040798000,
        "values": {
            "ts": 1633040798000,
            "longitude": 153.3986483,
            "latitude": -27.9003466,
            "alt": 6,
            "angle": 173,
            "sat": 16,
            "speed": 46,
            "Total Odometer": 24153145,
            "External Voltage": 14677
        }
    }
}, {
    "deviceName": "864292042802023",
    "deviceType": "tracker",
    "attributes": {
        "last_seen": 1633040864382,
        "sensorModel": "FMC130",
        "application": "Vehicle Tracker",
        "integrationName": "Teltonika FMC130",
        "Total Odometer": 24153254,
        "GSM Signal": 5,
        "External Voltage": 14670,
        "Battery Voltage": 3915,
        "Battery Current": 0,
        "GNSS Status": 1,
        "Ignition": 0,
        "Movement": 1,
        "Active GSM Operator": 50501
    },
    "telemetry": {
        "ts": 1633040807000,
        "values": {
            "ts": 1633040807000,
            "longitude": 153.3987583,
            "latitude": -27.90132,
            "alt": 3,
            "angle": 174,
            "sat": 16,
            "speed": 43,
            "Total Odometer": 24153254,
            "External Voltage": 14670
        }
    }
}]
```